# Way to Send Push Notification Uraban Airship using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, push-notification, urbanairship.com

Ive tried creating an ajax call to send a broadcast message to my development device using urban airship push services. The call works great using the portal website. but tried to use it as ajax call and no luck it doesn't bring back an error or success. Would someone know how to check the following code?

```
var ruleObj = {

    "aps": {
      "badge": 15,
      "alert": "Hello from Urban Airship!",
      "sound": "cat.caf"
 }
```

};

```
var objStr = JSON.stringify(ruleObj);

    jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){ 


        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType:"application/json",
        username: "Key ID NUM",
        password: "Master ID NUM",
        url:"https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/broadcast/",
                    data: objStr,

            success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the request parameters to -

`"Key ID NUM":"Master ID NUM",`